# Display ONLY the product name in 3 languages

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, products, localisation, language

This is my very first project in Magento 1.9, this is all about online grocery store. Where fruits & vegetables, rice & wheat, dry fruits, spices, etc etc are sold.

I am through with the installation process of Magento and 3rd party Template on server, setting up of categories & products. I passed this phase and successfully done it on my testing server.

Now what **I need is to display ONLY the name of products in 3 different languages (English, Hindi, and Bangla)**. I don't require the translation of whole website or web page, **ONLY** the name product example: Black Brinjal (રીંગણ ગોળ)(बैंगन). I know there are many tool/extension available for translation, but I think those all are for translating the complete store, which is in my case not required.

So I need some guidance on How can I get what actually I need. For better understanding kindly refer the images below which are from this website [truemart](http://truemart.in/fresh-fruits-and-vegetables/fresh-vegetables)-

[image: Product image with name in 2 languages]

It will be highly appreciable if any suggestion, advice or guidance is given to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

1. While adding or importing products you can add three languages together in Name field as

`Black Brinjal (રીંગણ ગોળ)(बैंगन)`.

It will display in frontend.

else

2. Product name comes from below files in line 58 approx.

   ```
   /app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
   ```

Add the logic to translate the only Name string with the help of [Google Transalate API](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-google-translate-api-php/)

Comment: Thank You for considering my issue. I have a doubt, if go for 1 option suggested by you, then how Magento will get the font of Hindi or Bangla. Do I need to do some tuning for fonts also in Magento or in Template.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the store language in English but add two new attributes "name_hindi" and "name_bangla" in catalog > attribute management. Mark them as "used in product listing" to make them available in all templates, then change the templates where the name is displayed to something like

```
<?php echo $product->getName()?>
<span class="hindi">
    <?php echo $product->getNameHindi()?>
</span>
<span class="bangla">
    <?php echo $product->getNameBangla()?>
</span>
```

Now you can change the font for each language based on the CSS class